# implementing a delegate

Tags: ios, delegates, ios5, uigesturerecognizer, uiapplicationdelegate

Im trying to follow this article for having simultaneous pan and pinch gesture recognizers but im unsure when I would call this method:

```
  #pragma mark - UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

Currently I have a pan and pinch gesture recognizer so i can use the methods he is explaining. I add the boolean method as well, but where exactly would I call it?

the article:   [1]: http://www.mindtreatstudios.com/our-projects/ios-gesture-recognizer-tips-tricks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call it, the gesture recogniser will call that method to tell you something of interest has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Gary is correct, for it to be called you would need your two recognizers to have the proper delegate set (likely self).